# All Yum mirrors failing with [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink

Tags: centos, yum

jq install is failing intermittently with this error.

```
http://mirrors.syringanetworks.net/fedora-epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
https://mirrors.xmission.com/fedora-epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
http://mirror.prgmr.com/pub/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
http://mirror.sfo12.us.leaseweb.net/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
https://dfw.mirror.rackspace.com/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
https://ord.mirror.rackspace.com/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
http://fedora.westmancom.com/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
http://fedora.mirrors.pair.com/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
http://mirror.nodesdirect.com/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
http://mirror.twinlakes.net/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
https://mirror.mrjester.net/fedora/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
https://mirror.vcu.edu/pub/gnu+linux/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
https://epel.mirror.constant.com/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
http://mirror.pit.teraswitch.com/fedora/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
http://mirror.siena.edu/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
https://mirror.dst.ca/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
https://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/fedora/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
https://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
http://packages.oit.ncsu.edu/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
http://mirrors.mit.edu/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
https://sjc.edge.kernel.org/fedora-buffet/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
https://mirror.atl.genesisadaptive.com/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
https://download-cc-rdu01.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
https://mirrors.upr.edu/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
https://mirror.arizona.edu/fedora-epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
http://mirror.oss.ou.edu/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
https://mirrors.sonic.net/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
https://ewr.edge.kernel.org/fedora-buffet/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
http://mirrors.kernel.org/fedora-epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
http://fedora-epel.mirrors.tds.net/fedora-epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
http://mirror.team-cymru.com/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
http://mirror.metrocast.net/fedora/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
https://mirror.dal.nexril.net/fedora-epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
https://mirror.chpc.utah.edu/pub/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
http://mirror.grid.uchicago.edu/pub/linux/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
http://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
https://mirror.csis.ysu.edu/fedora/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
https://linux-mirrors.fnal.gov/linux/fedora/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
https://mirror.umd.edu/fedora/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
https://mirrors.lug.mtu.edu/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
https://d2lzkl7pfhq30w.cloudfront.net/pub/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
https://mirror.steadfastnet.com/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
http://mirror.coastal.edu/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
http://mirror.rnet.missouri.edu/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
http://mirror.its.dal.ca/pub/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
https://mirror.us-midwest-1.nexcess.net/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
http://reflector.westga.edu/repos/Fedora-EPEL/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
https://iad.mirror.rackspace.com/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
http://mirrors.liquidweb.com/fedora-epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
http://mirror.compevo.com/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://mirror.compevo.com/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Connection timed out after 30006 milliseconds')
http://dl.iad2.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: dl.iad2.fedoraproject.org; Unknown error"
```

Is anyone else facing the same issue?

Comment: Yes, I'm also seeing this and trying to figure out why. Clearing cached data as suggested below didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your system has cached metadata that doesn't match the current state of the EPEL repository. Try clearing the metadata cache, then try your installation again.

```
yum clean metadata
```

Or just clear all cached data:

```
yum clean all
```

Comment: What's the downvote for?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the `repomd.xml` file hosted by the various mirrors has a *newer* timestamp than expected, given by the metalink URL:

For example, `https://mirror.vcu.edu/pub/gnu_linux/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml` returns:

```xml
<repomd>
  <revision>1591901338</revision>
  <!-- ... -->
</repomd>
```

While the metalink server tells Yum to expect:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<metalink version="3.0" xmlns="http://www.metalinker.org/" type="dynamic" pubdate="Sat, 13 Jun 2020 05:58:42 GMT" generator="mirrormanager" xmlns:mm0="http://fedorahosted.org/mirrormanager">
 <files>
  <file name="repomd.xml">
   <mm0:timestamp>1591551753</mm0:timestamp>
   <size>4851</size>
   <verification>
    <hash type="md5">34f2c5f5ac44cf223d5342364e2e9434</hash>
    <hash type="sha1">125df2220c97167ba37d86a71ac9468823231a94</hash>
    <hash type="sha256">801b295225be7b3f0c9f513093dfb0d374d85222a0f2d8324c97a0406b2ce6f1</hash>
    <hash type="sha512">50c451ab1918815e46266bd351aad6878dffd5b2c9ae31f94dad37de30a1224ad2e91b1790a0d416ad320091b0e4b989d4a18ff462c4d9913dea09bae0c53da4</hash>
   </verification>
   <!-- ... -->
  </file>
 </files>
</metalink>
```

The metalink `timestamp` 1591551753 < 1591901338 `revision` in the repomd file.

As a **workaround**, you can *comment* the `metalink` property in `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo` and *uncomment* the `baseurl`.  But this may have a negative impact on the mirror infrastructure and loses the security benefits of the metalink data; not something you want to run long-term.

Checking back several hours later, the metalink data has been updated with *both* revisions, which should correct the problem:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<metalink version="3.0" xmlns="http://www.metalinker.org/" type="dynamic" pubdate="Sat, 13 Jun 2020 15:07:38 GMT" generator="mirrormanager" xmlns:mm0="http://fedorahosted.org/mirrormanager">
 <files>
  <file name="repomd.xml">
   <mm0:timestamp>1591901393</mm0:timestamp>
   <size>5479</size>
   <verification>
    <hash type="md5">2f97fb4bae338fc659fb6c83fc0b4016</hash>
    <hash type="sha1">fbd5de037e5d8a77b7cf79d07c85fc7d54bc9892</hash>
    <hash type="sha256">db54f459b84db16d3385d94b6b59e22d71866d49b92b3e94318d3afb4fdd398b</hash>
    <hash type="sha512">557754859938ec9e772cceb549c99bfeb9a44296ee2811f58e3ae4ae7853cac207f754f02c6a1af87cc62b6680900e7d5c3542dc7539b1c58fe90b06805cc05a</hash>
   </verification>
   <mm0:alternates>
    <mm0:alternate>
      <mm0:timestamp>1591551753</mm0:timestamp>
      <size>4851</size>
      <verification>
       <hash type="md5">34f2c5f5ac44cf223d5342364e2e9434</hash>
       <hash type="sha1">125df2220c97167ba37d86a71ac9468823231a94</hash>
       <hash type="sha256">801b295225be7b3f0c9f513093dfb0d374d85222a0f2d8324c97a0406b2ce6f1</hash>
       <hash type="sha512">50c451ab1918815e46266bd351aad6878dffd5b2c9ae31f94dad37de30a1224ad2e91b1790a0d416ad320091b0e4b989d4a18ff462c4d9913dea09bae0c53da4</hash>
      </verification>
    </mm0:alternate>
   </mm0:alternates>
   <!-- ... -->
  </file>
 </files>
</metalink>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
yum makecache  fast
```

Will refresh your mirrors so that you get valid install sources.